# Odd inconsistent behavior of SQL Server "IN" clause

Tags: sql-server

**Query 1:**

```
select count(UserID)
from users
where UserID IN (select UserID from otherTable)
```

*Returns:* `178`

**Query 2:**: (simply changed `IN` to `NOT IN`)

```
select count(UserID)
from users
where UserID NOT IN (select UserID from otherTable)
```

*Returns:* `0`

**Query 3:** (remove the IN-clause completely)

```
select count(UserID)
from users
```

**Returns:** `1047123` (over a million)

What? I can't... Even...

The only explanation I have is my database in inconsistent/corrupted, I have to run DBCC CHECKDB or something.

PS. `UserID` is a primary key, so - no dupes.

Comment: `NOT IN` will not be true when a `NULL` is returned by the subquery. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406215/sql-select-where-not-in-subquery-returns-no-results. Use `NOT EXISTS` instead to avoid this gotcha.

Comment: @DanGuzman THANKS!!! You should move your comment to an answer, so I can upvote + accept

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NOT IN` will not evaluate to `true` when one or more `NULL` values are returned by the subquery.

Use `NOT EXISTS` to avoid this common gotcha. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406215/sql-select-where-not-in-subquery-returns-no-results) for more information and links to more detailed information.